# rtmplite/flashvideo-io: flv quality problem

Tags: flash, webcam, rtmp

I'm using [rtmplite](http://code.google.com/p/rtmplite/) as a flash media server and [flashvideo-io](http://code.google.com/p/flash-videoio/) (in a django website) for recording videos with the webcam.

No matter what quality parameter I set within the embedded object, I still get 10KB per second, recording very low quality videos, with 10 frames per second.

Is there a way to set the quality and the resolution of the recorded flvs to higher values?

Thanks

Although

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer needed, I was given by the developer a new sfw object with default HQ parameters.